# Why do we put "e" in our catch argument, in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

**For instance:**

```
try{

Parser p = Parser();  
    Expression exp = p.parse(expression);
    ContextModel cm = ContextModel();
      evaluated = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);
      result = '$evaluated'; 

}

catch(e)

{

result = "no";

}
```

**I see a lot of flutter related youtube tutorials simply putting "e" as their argument in the catch. Why do we do this? Does e simply mean any type of error?**

Comment: Why don’t you check the manual first? https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no special meaning, e is used as a placeholder. You can actually put any letter or allowed symbol like (_), and it will still represent the exception type incoming when error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of catch is the exception object that is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the name of exeption, you can call it "exeption" or "e" . In most cases you`re going to see this written as "e" - short for exeption or error.